# What is the difference between these two convergence notations: $f_n \to f$ and $f_n \nearrow f$ or $f_n \searrow f$

Tags: real-analysis, notation, convergence-divergence

I sometimes see this notation for convergence (speaking for functions): $f_n \to f$. And sometimes, I see following: $f_n \nearrow f$ or $f_n \searrow f$. What is the difference between $\to$ and other two?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer thanks. It was hard to embed all information to the header, but I tried. I hope it is OK. Thanks.

Comment: Now it's perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first generally means that the sequence of functions is pointwise non-decreasing, the second that it’s pointwise non-increasing. Sometimes a strict ordering is meant instead, so that the sequences are pointwise strictly increasing and pointwise strictly decreasing, respectively.

Comment: OK, then $\to$ can mean one of these $\nearrow$ or $\searrow$?

Comment: @John: Yes, but $\to$ also covers non-monotonic convergence.

Comment: Brian: now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @John: You’re welcome!